# Zf2 How to pass arguments using filter class?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, filter, zend-framework2

I would like to use SeparatorToSeparator() filter in zend framwork 2 to filter my data.
How can I pass two arguments(setSearchSeparator and setReplacementSeparator) to the constructor?

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
    'name' => 'supplierName',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        array('name'=>"Word\SeparatorToSeparator"
    ),
));
```

Path:zendframework/bin/libary/Zend/Filter/Word/SeparatorToSeparator.php

```
class SeparatorToSeparator extends AbstractFilter
{
    protected $searchSeparator = null;
    protected $replacementSeparator = null;



       /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param  string  $searchSeparator      Separator to search for
         * @param  string  $replacementSeparator Separator to replace with
         */
        public function __construct($searchSeparator = ' ', $replacementSeparator = '-')
        {
            $this->setSearchSeparator($searchSeparator);
            $this->setReplacementSeparator($replacementSeparator);
        }
```

**Updated**

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
            'name' => 'supplierName',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'=>'Word\SeparatorToSeparator',
                      'options' => array(
                                    'search_separator'      => 'a',
                                    'replacement_separator' => 'b'
                                )
                     )
            ),
        ));
```

I got this error message:

> Warning: preg_quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   C:\wamp\www\tebipdevelopment\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Filter\Word\SeparatorToSeparator.php
>   on line 92

I've opened this line and I have printed the error message like this.

```
print_r($this->searchSeparator);
print_r($this->replacementSeparator);
```

**Result**

### Array ( [search_separator] => a [replacement_separator] => b )

In that case the search_separator is equals to array instead of string

Comment: Don't use a constructor, use setOptions as the other filters do then you can have the options passed through for you. no need for a consructor.

Answer (score 3):

Note you don't need setters, but i've added them in anyway, the filter will try and use setters if they exist (setCamelCase() notation).

```
class SeparatorToSeparator extends AbstractFilter
{
    protected $searchSeparator = null;
    protected $replacementSeparator = null;

    public function setSearchSeparator($val)
    {
        $this->searchSeparator = $val;
    }

    public function setReplacementSeparator($val)
    {
        $this->replacementSeparator = $val;
    }
}
```

Now you can set the options:

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
    'name' => 'supplierName',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        array(
           'name'=>"Word\SeparatorToSeparator"
           'options' => array(
               'search_separator'      => 'bla',
               'replacement_separator' => 'bla'
           )
        )
    ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks,Dont know why I god this error message:  Warning: preg_quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\tebipdevelopment\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Filter\Word\SeparatorToSeparator.php on line 90

Comment: Are you using a # symbol as your separator?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up against this same issue, unlike other validators, the word validators don't accept an array of options, as you've found. The workaround I used was to just instantiate the word filter first, passing it the required constructor params, and then add that instance to the filters spec...

```
$wordFilter = new \Zend\Filter\Word\SeparatorToSeparator('a', 'b');

$inputFilter->add(array(
    'name' => 'supplierName',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        $wordFilter,
    ),
));
```